# A rude security guard

Tags: pattern, password

I was walking down a street, when I see a door, with a security guard.

A man approaches him, and the guard flips a middle on him.

*"Well that escalated quickly."* you think.

The man, unfazed, replied "4."

The guard allowed him to pass.

When another man approaches, the guard did not stick one, but two middle fingers.

The second man now replies, "132."

At this time, you are completely bewildered.

You decide to approach the guard. He looks at you, and he throws both pinkies up, and sticks them together.

**What do you say?**

Comment: I keep reading the title as "A nude security guard" ...

Comment: Along the same lines, "flips a middle". Nice euphemism.

Comment: Alternatively, you could flip someone of with the middle finger and the thumb, or the UK way, with the index and the rim, for ulterior puzzles

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You say

> $48$,

because

> the guard's fingers represent binary digits. Let the right thumb represent $2^0 = 1$, the right index finger represent $2^1 = 2$, and so on (see diagram). When a finger is extended, it represents a $1$ in that position, and an unextended finger represents a $0$.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Therefore, since the right middle finger represents $2^2=4$, the first man answers $0000000100_2=4_{10}$. The left middle finger represents $2^7=128$, thus two middle fingers represent $0010000100_2 = 132_{10}$, the second man's answer. You see the left and right pinkies extended, thus you answer $48$, since $0000110000_2=48_{10}$.

Comment: Enjoy your 2k privileges :-)!

Comment: Seems fitting if you could get to **2048** reputation for this answer.

Comment: @YowE3K Currently 2049. Doopliss, go and downvote an answer ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor I'll go downvote one of yours ;)

Comment: @Doopliss I'll upvote yours, to remove the temptation ;-) (actually not for that reason, but because it's a nice answer to a nice puzzle)

Comment: @randal'thor [Too late](http://imgur.com/gJXEi5c) ;) (But thank you!)

Comment: @Doopliss Who is the shooter? It'll be me if you don't watch out! :-P

Comment: Enjoy your (?) Third time's a Charm

Comment: @randal'thor I was hoping you would go with the `4, 128` threat, but you didn't. :P (Those of you that still don't get it: look at the picture in the answer.)

Comment: Whoa, what a binary treat :D

Answer (score 0):

My answer

> 48

My reasoning is that the guard must be using a code and I need to crack it as follows.

> The guard's questions are all powers of 2 indicated by fingers. The first question  was $2^2+0^1+0^0$. Correct answer was given,  $4+0+0=4$. The 2nd question was $2^7+2^2$. Correct answer was given, $128+4=132$. So my question was $2^5+2^4$. Gives, $32+16=48$.

QED

Comment: So this is what the accepted answer says?